# Unable to perform dragAndDrop function in webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Drag and drop is not working, please some buddy help me.

```
driver.get("http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop");

    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.className("result_output")));
    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText());
    Action dropImage = builder.dragAndDrop(driver.findElement(By.id("drag1")), driver.findElement(By.id("div1"))).build();
    dropImage.perform();
```

Comment: Are any `exceptions` thrown or any errors of any kind?

Comment: No, nothing, webdriver executed successfully but drag and drop not performed. You can also try above code.

Answer (score 0):

You seem not to be using the WebDriver returned from your driver.switchTo().frame().

Try this:

```
driver.get("http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop");

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebDriver frameDriver = driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.className("result_output")));

Actions builder = new Actions(frameDriver);
Action dropImage = builder.dragAndDrop(frameDriver.findElement(By.id("drag1")), frameDriver.findElement(By.id("div1"))).build();
dropImage.perform();
```

PS: Might this not be your issue: "Not working" is not quite descriptive enough. What happens? What do you see? Stacktrace? Error message? What is your output? do you actually get the iframe content?

Comment: after switch to iframe, i am unable to print the content of frame successfully. But unable to pick and drop image.

Comment: That means you are not switching correctly. Have you tried my code where you assign the driver.switchTo().frame() to a new WebDriver? Otherwise, is it really important to work with frames? Why not just use the content of the frame to start with? driver.get("http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryhtml5_draganddrop.htm");

Comment: i am able to print to content now but still issue with drag and drop of image with your code. Have you tried ?

Comment: You will need to provide some more information. It is quite likely that it does work but you just don't see it as it goes too fast. Debug and place a breakpoint after performing your action and see if it actually does not work. If it is not working, you will need to share more details. Browsers, selenium version, OS. Maybe an ElementNotFound exception is swallowed somewhere which can also be found by debugging. I have not tried the code, I'll leave that to you ;-)

Comment: I am using MAC-64 bit and latest Firefox version.

i have removed driver.close(); and driver.quit(); to check result in last. still having same issue.

Comment: Ok, I did give it a shot and it also fails for me. This looks to me that that pages script is not playing well with the webdriver for some reason. I do use this code a lot for jQuery and PrototypeJs drag and drop solutions. I'm sure you are not actually trying to test the w3schools website. Try it with a more applies page where you can control the drag drop code itself as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can watch test passing after running this code; However, it is not visible to us.
In actual, the drag & drop operation executes successfully.

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[id='iframeResult']")));
        Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(driver.findElement(By.id("drag1")))
        .moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("div1")))
        .release(driver.findElement(By.id("div1")))
        .build();
dragAndDrop.perform();
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Comment: Test is executed but image is not moving inside box.

Comment: @Khan Then try to use move with offset.